Bash script not launching correctly
Right now I am working on a project for which there is a custom conda environment. I created the environment and the project works, so I created a bash script to activate the conda environment, launch the project, and then deactivate the environment as the last step, so the end-user has to run this script and everything should go smoothly.
Launching the script from the terminal with bash script.sh or ./script.sh works just fine, the problem comes when I try to make sure that the script executes even if you double click on it. I was able to change the default behavior and other scripts that do just the same work fine, but this one in particular won't launch and I have no idea why.
For reference, here is the script that does work:
#!/bin/bash
source /home/<user>/miniconda3/bin/activate env1
fsleyes
conda deactivate

And here is the script that does not work
#!/bin/bash
source /home/<user>/miniconda3/bin/activate env2
python <folder>/mainwindow.py
conda deactivate

What did I get wrong?

Off the top of my head, is <folder>/mainwindow.py a relative path?

Yes, it is a relative path, but it seems strange that running from bash explicitly works, while running from the script doesn't

Well not really, I don't really remember from which path are scripts run through the DE run, but it makes sense that if that the relative path points to nothing the python script won't run :) I guess when you tried running the script using bash script.sh / ./script.sh you always did it from the "right" path? Try to change that to an absolute path and see if it works when executed from the DE.

That seemed to work, thank you very much. The problem is apparently that the shell took the path from the "wrong" starting point

Scripts run in GNOME by right-clicking the script and clicking on "Run as Program" will, by default, run in the executed script's directory;
As per the comments, <folder>/mainwindow.py is a relative path; so, if <folder>/mainwindow.py is not mainwindow.py's correct relative path from script.sh, either change <folder>/mainwindow.py to mainwindow.py's correct relative path from script.sh:
python path/to/mainwindow.py/from/script.sh

or (better) use an absolute path to identify mainwindow.py:
python /absolute/path/to/mainwindow.py

